# Ionic Webview Loading Black Screen on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on Ionic and I have noticed that while my app's webview is being loaded, black screen is shown. 
Is there a way to replace that black screen with a picture or at least to style to different color?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very easy. Its called splash screen.Take a   [look](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/). if you want to auto create this screens from one image take a look on this[Image Generation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html), if you need progress bar also then please thake a look on [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/)

```
    angular.module('LoadingApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoadingCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    }).then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
  };
  $scope.hide = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: $ionicLoading does not show untill Webview is fully loaded :(

Comment: that is correct. you should load first splash screen. the loading is for asy/long operations that isn't the case for you.

Comment: so basically I want to launch splash screen every time launch, but for some reason, if I turn off my ionic app with 'back' button and then turn on the app again, it would not show splash screen.

Comment: I found a solution. I read the doc of https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen and was able to find <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true|false" /> this line. If set false, it will launch splashcreen everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I read the doc of github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen and was able to find  this line. I added that line to config.xml. If set false, it will launch splashcreen everytime.